# What is wrong with my external jQuery File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a image slideshow. Currently, I have attached the event to a H1 element. Here is  my code stored in a file `main.js` in a folder `jq`:-

### *UPDATED CODE:*

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.browseImages = function(type) {
        var image = [];
        image[3] = "http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4006/5131022085_62876bbfbd_b.jpg";
        image[2] = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5201/5289991939_46a20dd9fd_o.jpg";
        image[1] = "http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2127/5807551517_72d39a1d19_b.jpg";

        var imageObject = $(this);
        var selection;

        if (type == "left") {
            for (var i=1; i < image.length; i++) {
                if (imageObject.attr("src") == image[i]) {
                    selection = i + 1;
                }
            }
            imageObject.attr("src",image[selection]);
        } else {
            for (var i=1; i < image.length; i++) {
                if (imageObject.attr("src") == image[i]) {
                    selection = i + 1;
                }
            }
            imageObject.attr("src",image[selection]);
        };
    }

})(jQuery);

$(function() { // <-- equivalent to $(document).ready(...)
    $("h1").click(function() {
        $('#image').browseImages("left");
    });
});
```

### *UPDATED CODE:*

(THE INIT HAs BEEN cOMMENTEd HERE) Here is my jQuery in the header tag of HTML:-

```
<!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="http://rhnvrm.co.cc/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="jq/main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <!--Initialize jQuery
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready( function() {
                    init()
                });
            </script>
            -->
```

And here is the Image in the body tag whose `src attr` I am editing:-

```
<div id="imageholder">
                <img id="image" src='http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2127/5807551517_72d39a1d19_b.jpg' width="900px" height="500px"/>
            </div>
```

---

NOTE: I am a person who you can categorize as a NOOB in jQuery

Comment: should you call your init function like $.init();

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: by the way, it could be way easier to use one of the many pre-existing jQuery slideshow plugins for this, especially if you're a beginner, unless you're coding this to learn more/practice.

Comment: @nideo - I am more of a PHP guy

Comment: @Rohan Verma, me too, but jQuery is very handy on the web.

Comment: @nideo Yea i just learnt that and am now employing it in one of my projects

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize an object or array called `image` before you can add items to it.

```
    var image = {};
    image[3] = "http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4006/5131022085_62876bbfbd_b.jpg";
    image[2] = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5201/5289991939_46a20dd9fd_o.jpg";
    image[1] = "http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2127/5807551517_72d39a1d19_b.jpg";
```

And if your function is the only one using `image`, I'd take it out of the function, and have it scoped in the IIFE:

```
(function($) {
    var image = {};
    image[3] = "http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4006/5131022085_62876bbfbd_b.jpg";
    image[2] = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5201/5289991939_46a20dd9fd_o.jpg";
    image[1] = "http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2127/5807551517_72d39a1d19_b.jpg";

    function browseImages(type) {
          // you could take `imageObject` out of this function as well if the
          //    element with the ID "image" never changes.
          //  v--------------------------------------------------------------
        var imageObject = $("#image");
        var selection;

        if (type == "left") {
            for (var i=1; i < Things.length; i++) {
                if (imageObject.attr("src") == Things[i]) {
                    selection = i;
                }  // <--- removed semi-colon
            }  // <--- removed semi-colon

              // v----- use the cached object
            imageObject.attr("src",image[selection]);
        } else {
            for (var i=1; i < Things.length; i++) {
                if (imageObject.attr("src") == Things[i]) {
                    selection = i;
                }  // <--- removed semi-colon
            }  // <--- removed semi-colon

              // v----- use the cached object
            imageObject.attr("src",image[selection]);
        }  // <--- removed semi-colon
    }


    init = function() {
        $("h1").click( function() {
            browseImages("left")
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

---

**EDIT:** After some clarification, here's a simpler solution:

```
(function($) {
    var image = [
        "http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2127/5807551517_72d39a1d19_b.jpg",
        "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5201/5289991939_46a20dd9fd_o.jpg",
        "http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4006/5131022085_62876bbfbd_b.jpg"
        ];

    var imageObject = $("#image");
    var selection = 0;

    function browseImages(type) {

        if (type == "left") {
            selection = ++selection % image.length
        } else {
            selection = (selection || image.length);
            --selection;
        }
        imageObject.attr("src", image[selection]);
    }

    init = function() {
        $("h1").click(function() {
            browseImages("left")
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
jQuery(document).ready( init );
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/37TeW/ I uploaded ur code here and even on my localhost but it does not work. can you please help

Comment: what do you mean my cached object?

Comment: @Rohan: `var imageObject = $("#image");` You cached `$("#image")` in the `imageObject` variable, but then ran `$("#image")` a couple additional times anyway. I simply replaced it with the variable.

Comment: ...I'll take a look at the fiddle. EDIT: In the fiddle, you have `MooTools` selected in the menu on the left instead of `jQuery`.

Comment: I thought that since I already included it in the HTML, It won't give an error.

Comment: ...Also, you don't have a `Things` variable that I can see.

Comment: ...Yes, I didn't see that you were loading jQuery there.

Comment: Oh yeah, thats correct, I use Aptana so it automatically created the for loop. LOL moment. I need to replace it with the image array

Comment: @Rohan: In that case, you need to make `image` an Array with `[]` instead of an object as I did in my code with `{}`. So: `var image = [];`

Comment: I updated the Fiddle(`http://jsfiddle.net/37TeW/1/`) I tested it on my `Localhost` but still dont work

Comment: @Rohan: I'm not getting the jQuery library from your server.

Comment: @Rohan: Doesn't load for me. Stalls after several seconds. Anyway, another issue with the fiddle is that you have the `ready()` code in the HTML, but the `init` assignment in the "Javascript" panel, so the `ready()` is running before `init` has been assigned. Move it all to the "Javascript" panel.

Comment: ...also, you're using `$` outside your scoping function: `(function($){/*...*/})(jQuery)` so there may be a conflict with `MooTools`.

Comment: ...so what are you trying to do anyway? Are you trying to change the image once with each click of the `<h1>`?

Comment: @Rohan: It is much simpler than you're making it. Move the `selection` variable outside the `browseImages` function, and it will retain a reference to the currently selected index. Also, start your Array on index `0` instead of `1` since that's where it should naturally start. [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jQyvR/2/) I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use a closure to protect the global scope (which is good), but forget to provide external interfaces for the functionality.

It's not entirely clear from your code, but I presume what you want is something like this:

```
// inside your browseImages function
var imageObject = $(this);

// somewhere near the bottom
$.fn.browseImages = browseImages; // so that you can use it like
```

And what your're doing in `init()` function doesn't really belong to the plugin that you are making. You can move the whole init function directly to `$(document).ready(...)`

**UPDATE**

Complete code for `main.js`

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.browseImages = function(type) {
        var image = [];
        image[3] = "http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4006/5131022085_62876bbfbd_b.jpg";
        image[2] = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5201/5289991939_46a20dd9fd_o.jpg";
        image[1] = "http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2127/5807551517_72d39a1d19_b.jpg";

        var imageObject = $(this);
        var selection;

        if (type == "left") {
            for (var i=1; i < Things.length; i++) {
                if (imageObject.attr("src") == Things[i]) {
                    selection = i;
                }
            }
            imageObject.attr("src",image[selection]);
        } else {
            for (var i=1; i < Things.length; i++) {
                if (imageObject.attr("src") == Things[i]) {
                    selection = i;
                }
            }
            imageObject.attr("src",image[selection]);
        };
    }

})(jQuery);

$(function() { // <-- equivalent to $(document).ready(...)
    $("h1").click(function() {
        $('#image').browseImages("left");
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't move it to the $(document).ready event since I don't want to hog the space in my index.php

Comment: OK. Then you can just as well move "jQuery initialization" inside the `main.js` (but leave it outside the closure). And also expose the `init()` function, like `$.init = init;` and then in doc.ready call `$.init()`

Comment: do you mean that I should include this `$(document).ready( function() {
     init()
    });` into main.js?

Comment: Please see updated code. Also, it's unclear what `Things` are, but I hope they are defined somewhere else; Also, your if/else blocks are identical - doesn't make sense (work in progress?)